# Can't add task to the function that returns pipeline (Airflow, DAG)

Tags: python, airflow

I have a function which we mainly use to add to the end of each DAG. Let's call it **finalize** and it looks like the following **Common** class (of course, in reality it's doing useful stuff). And what we usually do is almost for each DAG to the end we add the code like

task_1 >> task_2 >> ... task_n **>> common.finalize**

and as a result, we get

task_1 >> task_2 >> ... task_n **>> a >> b >> c**.

So far all is good. However, now for one of the DAGs I want to add a task after the **finalize**. I don't want to touch the finalize function and the code

**task_1 >> task_2 >> ... task_n >> common.finalize >> task_new**

doesn't help me, because the **task_new** starts immediately after **a**. But I want the **task_new** to be executed after **c**.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

```py
class Common(object):
    def __init__(self, dag):
        self.dag = dag

    @property
    def finalize(self):
        a = BashOperator(
            task_id='echo_dag',
            bash_command='echo "dag"',
            dag=self.dag)

        b = BashOperator(
            task_id='echo_has_completed',
            bash_command='echo "has completed"',
            dag=self.dag)

        c = BashOperator(
            task_id='echo_successfully',
            bash_command='echo "successfully"',
            dag=self.dag)

        a >> b >> c
        return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it sounds like you could set `task_new` to have a `trigger_rule` value of `all_success` to ensure that all upstream tasks have completed successfully before it's triggered, and then orchestrate the tasks like this:

`[task_1, task_2, task_n, common.finalize] >> [task_new]`

Comment: Sorry for not clear description. But it's not `trigger_rule`. The graph that's built is not correct. Because the function returns `a` which is the first task. By the way, even though it returns only `a`, the graph shows all 3 tasks (a >> b >> c) and airflow runs them as well. However, when I add the new task after the function it starts immediately after the task `a`, but I want it to be started after `c` which is the last task without touching the function.

Comment: Does removing `return a` from the finalize() function fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a tuple contain first and last task `a, c`. And then
`task_n >> common.finalize[0]
common.finalize[1] >> task_new`